# How to bounce dnsmasq in opensuse 13.1

Tags: opensuse, dnsmasq

OpenSuse 13.1 is missing the init.d dnsmasq script. Is there another way to start and stop dnsmasq or is this a bug in suse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with SuSE but on other distros you can use the `service` command to stop/start/restart services. Perhaps something like this would do it:

```
$ sudo service dnsmasq restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that another way to do this in OpenSuse and Suse is to use Services Manager GUI in YAST.

Just find the service nameed dnsmasq and ensure its enabled and you can start and stop from the GUI. Active = running, Inactive = stopped.

Answer (score 0):

With OpenSuSE switching to systemd completely in version 12.3, init.d scripts are slowly being phased out.

Although systemd can use init.d scripts, it much prefers .system files instead.

That all being said, OpenSuSE has some nice features that other distros don't have. For example, in OpenSuSE, `chckconfig foo on` still works to enable services. In other distros, it's been replaced by `systemctl enable foo` (OpenSuSE can make use of this as well).

As mentioned above, to start a service is through `service foo start`. In OpenSuSE, the most common way that I've seen is through `rcfoo start`; however, YaST will work as well. Other distros will use `systemctl start foo` (again, OpenSuSE can use this as well).